# Overriding an Obj-C class method from Swift which returns NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray

I seem unable to override the following method, and have created a standalone example which has been vexing me for a few hours now.

It's almost certainly something silly, but I seem unable to override a class method in a swift class, where the base class is Objective C, and specifically the return type is an `NSArray*`.

I just get the error, "`Method does not override any method from its superclass`"

So my failure is shown below:

[image: Error shown, with definition of class and superclass]

But it works fine if the return type is changed to something simple like NSString*

[image: Working example with NSString]

Now i've tried `Array<AnyObject>` and played around with a couple of others, but i'm still a bit fresh with the Swift syntax so i'm almost certainly missing something obvious.

Comment: @Kex how would that solve the problem?  The user is trying to implement a class method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSArray *` is bridged to Swift as `[AnyObject]!` (an implicitly-unwrapped `Array` of `AnyObject` instances).  Look at the generated Swift interface for `[ExampleBase exampleMethod]`:

[image: ExampleBase]

Change your method return type to `[AnyObject]!`.

```
override class func exampleMethod() -> [AnyObject]! {
    return []
}
```

To specify an optional or concrete value in your Swift subclass, use an Objective-C nullability specifier:

`+ (NSArray * _Nonnull)exampleMethod;` bridges to `override class func exampleMethod() -> [AnyObject]`

`+ (NSArray * _Nullable)exampleMethod;` bridges to `override class func exampleMethod() -> [AnyObject]?`

`+ (NSArray *)exampleMethod;` and `+ (NSArray * _Null_unspecified)exampleMethod;` have identical behavior and bridge to an implicitly-unwrapped optional.

Comment: Thx for the answer,  I thought I'd tried that!  But I'd missed off the ! At the end.  Good tip to check the definition,  no idea why I didn't try that.

Comment: right now looks like using Any: override func exampleMethod() -> [Any]!

Answer (score 4):

A solution is to give the compiler more information about the type.

In ObjC declare the method

```
+ (NSArray<NSString *>*)exampleMethod;
```

then in Swift you can write

```
override class func exampleMethod() -> [String]
```